# Azure Application Gateway - Multiple SSL Certificates?

Tags: azure

Is it possible to set multiple Domains to point to an Azure Application Gateway Public IP and then upload SSL Certificates for each one that can then Offload on the Application Gateway?

For example if we'd like to have 200 LetsEncrypt certificates uploaded and terminating at the gateway, then forwarding traffic onto the internal VM IPs

Comment: I have been through the docs here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/application-gateway-create-gateway/ but it's unclear whether you can terminate multiple domains or only a single domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application Gateway supports multi-site listeners, which can listen on a certain domain name and you can upload your certificates to each one of them. But the limit on the number of listeners is 100 as of now.

All the domain names that you have, can be CNAMEd to Application Gateway's FQDN and based on the hostname, you can create rules to specific backends.

See here for more info: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-multiple-sites-powershell